# Quartz produces unhandled null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

So, I have 2 schedulers set on different Spring profiles. When I run Spring scheduler everything works fine, but they want me to implement Quartz.

Here's a Job class:

```
@Profile("quartz")
@Component
public class SampleJob implements Job {

@Autowired
private GetDataServiceQuartz getDataServiceQuartz;

public SampleJob() {
}

public SampleJob(GetDataServiceQuartz getDataServiceQuartz) {
    this.getDataServiceQuartz = getDataServiceQuartz;
}

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {

    this.getDataServiceQuartz.storeData();
}
}
```

An error being thrown:

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception.
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.example.blockchaininfo.services.Quartz.SampleJob.execute(SampleJob.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
... 1 common frames omitted
```

A `nullPointerException` is being thrown on this particular line:

```
this.getDataServiceQuartz.storeData();
```

As soon as I've tried to print `this.getDataServiceQuartz` it prints `null`.

The class that does all the behind work:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@Profile("quartz")
public class GetDataServiceQuartz{

constructorHere();

public void storeData(){

        try {
            String hashrateFromApi = this.getNetworkHashrateFromApi("http://public.turtlenode.io:11898/getinfo");
            OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.now();

            this.saveNetworkHashrateNewEntity(hashrateFromApi, date);
            this.storePoolDataToDB(this.getPoolsListFromJson(), retrieveNetworkIdForPoolDefinition(date));

        } catch (HttpServerErrorException e){
            log.info("Network Server error e1: " + e);
        } catch (ResourceAccessException e2){
            log.info("Network resource access exception: " + e2);
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            log.info("" + e3);
        } catch (InterruptedException e4){
            log.info("" + e4);
        }
}

...all other methods to acquire stuff.
```

And Quartz configuration.

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent){

    this.startQuartzScheduling();
}

public void startQuartzScheduling () {

    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SampleJob.class)
            .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();

    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
            .withSchedule(
                    SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                            .withIntervalInSeconds(5).repeatForever())
            .build();

    try {
        Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    } catch (SchedulerException e){
        log.info("" + e);
    }
}
```

What am I missing? How to properly inject a class that should have its methods scheduled?

Comment: why do you need an empty constructor? it looks like your job is created using this empty constructor instead of one setting field. Have you tried to put `Autowired` on constructor instead of field

Comment: As soon as I remove the empty constructor I get `org.quartz.SchedulerException: Problem instantiating class 'com.example.blockchaininfo.services.Quartz.SampleJob'
` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is hapenning because quartz `JobBuilder` creates new instance of your `SampleJob` instead of using created one with autowired fields. And as it uses default constructor as the result you have nullpointer.

One option to fix this is to put your `GetDataServiceQuartz` to scheduler context.

Described [here](http://tech-lead.blogspot.de/2015/03/how-to-pass-parameters-to-quartz-job.html)

So, to put your data you need to call:

```
scheduler.getContext().put("getDataServiceQuartz", getDataServiceQuartz);
```

And when executing your task:

```
SchedulerContext schedulerContext = jobExecutionContext.getScheduler().getContext();
schedulerContext.get("getDataServiceQuartz");
```

Other, in my opinion more convenient way, is to put it to `JobDataMap` which will be available from your `SampleJob`:

```
job.getJobDataMap().put("getDataServiceQuartz", getDataServiceQuartz);
```

When executing task:

```
context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get("getDataServiceQuartz")
```

Full example can be found [here](https://www.concretepage.com/scheduler/quartz/quartz-2-scheduler-pass-parameters-to-job-with-jobdatamap-using-persistjobdataafterexecution-and-disallowconcurrentexecution-example).